# Block countries or IPs in Shopify

Tags: shopify

I'm looking for a way to block a country or range of IP addresses in a Shopify store. I do not have access to htaccess. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is no htaccess with shopify. The only way to block ip address (which is not a block but more of a redirect) would be to do it in javascript. You coud use a service like [ipdata](https://ipdata.co/index.html) to make a request to get the country code or ip and redirect the user accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have found a solution for redirecting but the traffic still skews my stats.